# How to access data from a function that return an ajax get json response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, response, ajax-request

I have a function that return json data using ajax:

```
function validateTagRequest(fileName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/tags/find-tag/"+fileName.tag,
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }
    });
};
```

`console.log(data)` show exactly what I need.

But then I call the function:

```
var response = validateTagRequest(fileName);
useResponse(response); // this don't work, response = undefined
console.log(response);
```

`console.log(response)` return undefined

How can I handle the asynchronous of js to execute this code in order?

Comment: you should understand that `data` is returned inside the success function of the $.ajax call.. not inside the validateTagRequest. that's why it's not accessible to you.

Answer (score -1):

try a callback

```
function validateTagRequest(fileName, cb) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/tags/find-tag/"+fileName.tag,
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
            cb(data);
        }
    });
}

validateTagRequest(fileName, function(response){
    useResponse(response);
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: and why this is supposed to work?